# What are the mechanical advantages of using Acrobatic Performer?

Tags: feats, optimization, pathfinder-2e

There seems to be no tangible purpose to pick up [Acrobatic Performer](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2106) beyond narrative. For example, it **cannot** be used to [Earn Income](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/190503/can-i-use-the-acrobatic-performer-feat-to-earn-income-using-the-acrobatics-skill) or to gain [Panache](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/190511/can-i-use-the-acrobatic-performer-feat-to-gain-panache-using-the-acrobatics-skil).

Does Acrobatic Performer provide mechanical advantages for any non-roleplay applications?

Comment: This question seems similar to my question here: [What is the utility of an unbreakable arrow?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170358/62294), which worked out just fine. There’s room for good subjective experience based answers here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The perform skill is used to perform. Acrobatic Performer allows you to use Acrobatics instead of your perform skill, except

### You can use it for the Perform action.

The scope of the [Performance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ID=12) skill is:

> You are skilled at a form of performance, using your talents to impress a crowd or make a living.

The Core Rules explicitly identify two actions within this general domain: the [Perform](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=59) action and the [Earn Income](https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ID=2&General=true) trained action.

Acrobatic Performer allows you to use Acrobatics instead of the Perform action. The Perform action has a fully described resolution path. On a success or critical success, the observers are pleased with your performance.

### Performance skill feats

One Performance skill feat explicitly uses the Perform action. [Fascinating Performance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=781) allows you to fascinate 1 observer.

Two others ([Distracting Performance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2122) and [Impressive Performance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=793)) reference the Performance skill, but do not refer to any specific action. Consult your GM to decide whether you can apply Acrobatic Performer or not.

### Lowering Diplomacy DCs and Changing Attitudes

Although there are many reasons you might care about a performance, the Perform action lays out one explicit outcome:

> "... it might influence the DCs of subsequent Diplomacy checks against the observers - or even change their attitudes - if the GM sees fit.

The rules for Diplomacy describe attitudes.

Acrobatic Performer therefore allows you to use the Perform action with Acrobatics (instead of Performance), also allowing you to change the DCs of future Diplomacy checks and perhaps changing attitudes.

Comment: I'm not sure how much, but Shadowdancer gets a Focus spell that requires a Perform check and I think Bard has some things that require rolling it

Comment: @Ifusaso, Bards generally do not want to replace a Cha based roll.

Comment: True, but they may want Acrobatics for other things and have Legendary Acro but only Trained Performance. Still unlikely, but possible... *shrug*

Comment: Someone with high Dex but middling Cha who picks up a Bard dedication might still want to make Perform checks via Acrobatics, so both Shadowdancer and Bard are relevant here.